# why an angular component is not replaced by its template

Tags: angular

I work on an angular 10 application.
In a parent component, I add the tag of a child component

the template of the parent component

```
...........
.............
    <app-child-component (...)="..."
                           [...]="..."
                           [...]="..."
                           [...]="..."></app-child-component>
............
...........
```

And the child component is the following

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-child-component",
  template: `
    <form>
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="true" >text</mat-checkbox>
......................
......................
```

but I cannot see the child template in my browser. I just see

```
<app-child-component _ngcontent-rps-c389=""></app-child-component>
```

It must be obvious, but I cannot see what's happening

Comment: Should work fine. Not enough information to determine why it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the application and everything has been put in order. It must be due to some desynchronization. The discussion is closed. Thank you